# Magento 2 Custom Js does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I have add a custom.js file under my_child theme folder web/js/custom.js

here is code

```
define([
  "jquery"
], 
function($) {
        "use strict";

        $('#shipping').find('.step-title').click(function(){

          //Expand or collapse this panel
          $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');

          //Hide the other panels
          $(".step-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');

        });

        console.log('My log');
});
```

I have create requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
  deps: [
    "js/custom"
  ]
};
```

'My log' is print on console but jquery accordion does not works. If i copy and past custom.js function on browser console it works fine

website is in developer mode
how can i debug?

Comment: load the js after content load then check.

Comment: just try with define([jquery','domReady!'] but it load before all why?

Answer (score 1):

solved in this way. thanks to Lucas

```
define([
  'jquery','rjsResolver'
], 
function($, resolver) {
        "use strict";

        resolver( function (){
            $('#shipping').find('.step-title').click(function(){

          //Expand or collapse this panel
          $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');

          //Hide the other panels
          $(".step-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');

        });

        console.log('Accordion Eseguito');      
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I was working for 2 days to resolve jQuery plugin. Thanks again.